# NodeJs http.get for Dart

Tags: node.js, dart

In Node.js I can do:

```
var http = require('http')

var url = 'mylinkedsite.com'
http.get({ host: url }, function(){...})
```

In Dart I'm trying the same:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:uri';

var url = 'mylinkedsite.com';        
var client = new HttpClient();
var uri = new Uri.fromString(url);
var connection = client.getUrl(uri);
connection.onResponse = (res){...};
```

But I am unable to get the same result without the url.scheme and url.path explicitly added. Both of which are final. What's the simplest way to accomplish the same result.

Comment: So you're asking for an HTTP client with an API closer to the http lib shipped with Node? It looks like your code snippet is (at the present time) the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpClient in [dart:io](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/HttpClient.html) supports strings as hostnames:

```
  var conn = httpClient.get("http://mylinkedsite.com", 80, "/");
  conn.onResponse = (HttpClientResponse response) {
    if(response.statusCode != 200) {
       // unexpected return code
    } else {
       // success, parse response
    }
  };
  conn.onError = (e) => completer.completeException(e);
```

only other method is http helper method to hide the URI call's behind a more node like interface.

Comment: Node seems to check for and add the scheme: 'http://' and path: '/' if they're missing in http.get. Would be nice if Dart had the same for those trying to make the switch from Node.